# How do I solve this reference error when opening a file?

Tags: discord, referenceerror

### I'm trying to make a discord bot that can read dates from a txt file on my device.

I've read the documentation and looked over similar posts, but I keep running into the same error. Just starting to learn python so please excuse any obvious mistakes/ strange formatting.

---

```
    list = open("dates.txt","r")

    list.seek(0)

    var firstLine = file1.readline()         

    file1.close()

    bot.sendMessage({

        to: channelID,

        message: firstLine
    })
```

---

The error:

```
  C:\Users\My Laptop\Desktop\Discord Bots\HeadzUp\bot.js:241
            list = open("dates.txt","r")
            ^

ReferenceError: open is not defined
    at DiscordClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\My Laptop\Desktop\Discord Bots\HeadzUp\bot.js:241:13)
    at DiscordClient.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at DiscordClient.handleWSMessage (C:\Users\My Laptop\Desktop\Discord Bots\HeadzUp\node_modules\discord.io\lib\index.js:1854:11)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Receiver.ontext (C:\Users\My Laptop\Desktop\Discord Bots\HeadzUp\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:841:10)
    at C:\Users\My Laptop\Desktop\Discord Bots\HeadzUp\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:536:18
    at Receiver.applyExtensions (C:\Users\My Laptop\Desktop\Discord Bots\HeadzUp\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:371:5)
    at C:\Users\My Laptop\Desktop\Discord Bots\HeadzUp\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:508:14
    at Receiver.flush (C:\Users\My Laptop\Desktop\Discord Bots\HeadzUp\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:347:3)
    at Receiver.finish (C:\Users\My Laptop\Desktop\Discord Bots\HeadzUp\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:541:12)
PS C:\Users\My Laptop\Desktop\Discord Bots\HeadzUp>
```

---

Might be useful to know

- This bot is able to do other things like respond to commands
- dates.txt exists in the same folder at C:\Users\My Laptop\Desktop\Discord Bots\HeadzUp

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: That doesn't look like Python code nor Python error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   The code you are running is nodejs.  Not Python.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems like I completely mashed up python and nodejs on accident.
Not quite sure what I was thinking but that was the issue.

---

Simple answer — don't mix nodejs and Python.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should avoid to redefine "list" as this is python keyword.
Second, the command is correct and the "open" keyword is built in in native python. So it should work.
This exact line works in my python environment (even when overwriting "list").

When you look at the end of the lines of the error message you can see the ".js" endings. This is hinting, that you somehow try to interpret python code with a javascript interpreter.
Maybe you should post some more information about your system and setup.

If you use a proper python3 interpreter your code should work.

Comment: it won't work. it's not python code

Comment: Yeah. I agree. Some of the lines will work in python, but not all of them. Considering the title mentioned python explicitly (before the edit). I was assuming they are trying to use python but were confused about the correct interpreter.
Now I assume there is more to the file above and it's only a snippet from a file that is obviously in js.